# Heroku thinks I'm trying to install Ruby 2.5.1 in my app, won't deploy

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Heroku and am not a developer, but am following directions on how to create an app based on a template. The instructions are here btw:
https://github.com/syncforynab/fintech-to-ynab/wiki/Getting-Started

And here's the template:
https://heroku.com/deploy?template=https://github.com/scottrobertson/fintech-to-ynab

Anyway, everything seems to be fine until I hit Deploy. I'm getting the below message that the script is trying to install Rub 2.5.1 and that's too old. I contacted the developer at Github and he said it must be a Heroku glitch as they specify a higher version. Anyone know what's going on here?

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Installing bundler 1.17.3
-----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
       Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-20/ruby-2.5.1.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 1 of 3.
       Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-20/ruby-2.5.1.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 2 of 3.
 !
 !     The Ruby version you are trying to install does not exist on this stack.
 !     
 !     You are trying to install ruby-2.5.1 on heroku-20.
 !     
 !     Ruby ruby-2.5.1 is present on the following stacks:
 !     
 !     - cedar-14
 !     - heroku-16
 !     - heroku-18
 !     
 !     Heroku recommends you use the latest supported Ruby version listed here:
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
 !     
 !     For more information on syntax for declaring a Ruby version see:
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Does your Gemfile specify the Ruby version you want?

Comment: The deploy template uses a different code base which shows 2.5.1  https://github.com/scottrobertson/fintech-to-ynab/blob/master/Gemfile. Maybe you can change the link to: https://heroku.com/deploy?template=https://github.com/syncforynab/fintech-to-ynab and see if that works. You can also just click the Deploy button link on the github page